# Errors in compiling FFmpeg for windows10/aarch64 using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Preview edition

Tags: ffmpeg, arm, chromium, arm64, armasm

I am trying to compile FFmpeg (the Chromium version) for Windows10/Aarch64 configuration using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Preview community edition. I am running into errors in the assembly files as copied below (highlighted few errors). I believe FFmpeg is working for Linux/Aarch64 configuration (probably using GNU assembler) already in which case the same assembly code should also work for Microsoft ARM Macro Assembler as well. Please let me know if I am missing anything here and any pointers to help resolve the errors.

D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src>ninja -C out\ARM64V8 third_party\ffmpeg
ninja: Entering directory `out\ARM64V8'
[2/9] ASM obj/third_party/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_internal/autorename_libavcodec_aarch64_fft_neon.obj
FAILED: obj/third_party/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_internal/autorename_libavcodec_aarch64_fft_neon.obj
D:/Work/Chromium_FFmpeg/depot_tools/win_tools-2_7_6_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../build/toolchain/win/tool_wrapper.py asm-wrapper environment.arm64 armasm64.exe  /Foobj/third_party/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_internal/autorename_libavcodec_aarch64_fft_neon.obj ../../third_party/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aarch64/autorename_libavcodec_aarch64_fft_neon.S
**Microsoft (R) ARM Macro Assembler Version 14.16.26926.0 for 64 bits**
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\autorename_libavcodec_aarch64_fft_neon.S(1) : **error A2003: improper line syntax: /**
// File automatically generated. See crbug.com/495833.
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\autorename_libavcodec_aarch64_fft_neon.S(2) : **error A2230: Illegal preprocessor directive; only "#line  [filename]" is recognized**
include "fft_neon.S"
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\autorename_libavcodec_aarch64_fft_neon.S(3) : warning A4045: missing END directive
include "fft_neon.S"
.
.
.
[6/9] ASM obj/third_party/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_internal/mpegaudiodsp_neon.obj
FAILED: obj/third_party/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_internal/mpegaudiodsp_neon.obj
D:/Work/Chromium_FFmpeg/depot_tools/win_tools-2_7_6_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../build/toolchain/win/tool_wrapper.py asm-wrapper environment.arm64 armasm64.exe  /Foobj/third_party/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_internal/mpegaudiodsp_neon.obj ../../third_party/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aarch64/mpegaudiodsp_neon.S
Microsoft (R) ARM Macro Assembler Version 14.16.26926.0 for 64 bits
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(1) : **error A2003: improper line syntax: /**
/*
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(2) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Janne Grunau 
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(3) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 *
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(4) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * This file is part of FFmpeg.
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(5) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 *
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(6) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * FFmpeg is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(7) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(8) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(9) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(10) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 *
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(11) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * FFmpeg is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(12) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(13) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(14) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(15) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 *
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(16) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(17) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * License along with FFmpeg; if not, write to the Free Software
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(18) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(19) : error A2079: improper line syntax; symbol expected
 */
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(21) : error A2230: Illegal preprocessor directive; only "#line  [filename]" is recognized
include "libavutil/aarch64/asm.S"
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(23) : error A2230: Illegal preprocessor directive; only "#line  [filename]" is recognized
define FRAC_BITS   23   // fractional bits for sb_samples and dct
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(24) : error A2230: Illegal preprocessor directive; only "#line  [filename]" is recognized
define WFRAC_BITS  16   // fractional bits for window
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(25) : error A2230: Illegal preprocessor directive; only "#line  [filename]" is recognized
define OUT_SHIFT (WFRAC_BITS + FRAC_BITS - 15)
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(27) : error A2034: unknown opcode: tbl_rev128_s
const   tbl_rev128_s, align=4
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(28) : **error A2034: unknown opcode: .**
        .byte           12, 13, 14, 15
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(29) : error A2034: unknown opcode: .
        .byte            8,  9, 10, 11
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(30) : error A2034: unknown opcode: .
        .byte            4,  5,  6,  7
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(31) : error A2034: unknown opcode: .
        .byte            0,  1,  2,  3
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(34) : error A2003: improper line syntax: .
.macro   apply_window   type, st
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(35) : **error A2034: unknown opcode: ff_mpadsp_apply_window_**
function ff_mpadsp_apply_window_\type()_neon, export=1
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(42) : error A2034: unknown opcode: movrel
        movrel          x15, tbl_rev128_s
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(44) : error A2003: improper line syntax: .
.ifc \type, fixed
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(46) : error A2003: improper line syntax: .
.else
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(48) : error A2003: improper line syntax: .
.endif
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(53) : **error A2173: syntax error in expression**
        sub             x5,  x5,  x4            // samples2
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(53) : error A2003: improper line syntax: Trouble parsing operands
        sub             x5,  x5,  x4            // samples2
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(54) : error A2173: syntax error in expression
        neg             x13, x4                 // -incr
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(54) : error A2003: improper line syntax: Trouble parsing operands
        neg             x13, x4                 // -incr
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(56) : error A2003: improper line syntax: .
.ifc \type, fixed
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(57) : error A2173: syntax error in expression
        ld1r            {v16.2s}, [x2]          // dither_state
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(57) : error A2003: improper line syntax: Trouble parsing operands
        ld1r            {v16.2s}, [x2]          // dither_state
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(60) : error A2061: illegal expression type; expected absolute numeric
        movi            v30.2d, #(1<error A2034: unknown opcode: MLA2
        MLA2            v17, v2, v0
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(93) : error A2034: unknown opcode: MLS2
        MLS2            v19, v3, v6
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(95) : error A2034: unknown opcode: MLS2
        MLS2            v17, v4, v7
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(97) : error A2034: unknown opcode: MLS2
        MLS2            v19, v5, v1
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(98) : error A2034: unknown opcode: .
        b.gt            2b
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(101) : error A2173: syntax error in expression
        sub             x10, x10, #64<<5        // 64 * 8 * sizeof(int32_t)
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(101) : error A2003: improper line syntax: Trouble parsing operands
        sub             x10, x10, #64<<5        // 64 * 8 * sizeof(int32_t)
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(103) : error A2003: improper line syntax: .
.ifc \type, fixed
D:\Work\Chromium_FFmpeg\chromium\src\third_party\ffmpeg\libavcodec\aarch64\mpegaudiodsp_neon.S(105) : error A2034: unknown opcode: ext
        ext             v28.16b, v29.16b, v28.16b, #8
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe FFmpeg is working for Linux/Aarch64 configuration (probably using GNU assembler) already in which case the same assembly code should also work for Microsoft
>   ARM Macro Assembler as well.

The [Microsoft Arm Assembler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/arm/arm-assembler-reference?view=vs-2017) uses a different syntax to the GNU Assembler, similar but not quite the same as [the syntax used by armasm](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100069_0611_00_en/index.html). They are not compatible.